# Problem protecting a page with a password

Tags: plugins, password

As we know, there is a built-in option in WP to protect a certain page with a password. Under the general settings for the page, I choose to show it only with password and set the password accordingly. When visiting the page, indeed there is a text box for typing in the password and submit button.

The problem is that when I type in the password I set (the right one, I swear) and click the submit button, the page just reloads and shows the password text box again, without showing the regular content of the page. Without any error message, the password is absolutely right, and no indication why it is acting like that.

Now, I have looked around for it, and everything I've found is talking about a problem with the URLs of the site, as the reason for this situation. Well, I have no problem with the URLs of the site, as both are the same, as they've always been from when I created this site.

So, what is the cause of that? Is it a bug in WP that still exists in 4.9.1?
I don't think the issue is related to cookies or something like that in the browser, because cookies are not blocked (*and* it happens on every computer I've checked this on).

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that this situation happens regardless to cookies. Meaning, it will happen also on a computer that has never been to this page, or in Incognito mode of Chrome for example, and even after deleting all the cookies of the site and refreshing the page.

Comment: Have you tried using a default theme and/or switching off plugins to see if one of them may be causing a conflict?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have a confused cookie. Does this happen in another unused browser and/or in Private Browsing mode?

Comment: @DavidSword - see my update above...

Comment: This sound like a plugin or a function.php cannibalizes the flow. Deactivate all plugins clear the cookies and try again. If this not solves the issue give the list of the plugin you have and if there is something in function.php regarding redirection or caching.

Comment: Hi Try restarting apache or nginix on your server. It is not a theme or plugin issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the logical steps to find out the cause of the problem.

1. Remove the password and load the page, is it showing the page content? If not, the problem is within your page template. Be sure you use the WordPress post loop correctly
2. The the answer of your first question is yes, then we need to dig into the more complex things..

2.1. Go to WordPress permalink and flash it, or just can hit the below button, most of the time, just visiting the permalink page works

2.2. If the problem is still persist, uninstall the plugins one by one and check whether the problem persist. If you find a plugin that is causing the problem then you know what to do, most likely find a alternate plugin to fix the plugin.

2.3. If the problem still persist, switch the theme with default WordPress theme. The is the end of our steps and if the content is visible with the password, you definitely need to work on the theme functions to solve the problem.

Hope this helps
Sabbir H
The WP Guy